# How can I fade in a background image of jumbotron on mouseover and revert it back to previous backround image on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was designing a website using bootstrap and there is a jumbotron on my page.

The jumbotron has a background image. How can I fade in the current background image of the jumbotron on hover?

means if I take the cursor on the jumbotron, another background image fades in and when I take the cursor out of the jumbotron, the previous picture comes back.

Here is my Jumbotron html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Life is an Art.</h1>
    <p style="font-size: 150%"><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas pulvinar nunc urna, non cursus enim ultricies in.</small></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a href="#">Learn More »</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron { background-image: url("02.jpg"); }
.jumbotron:hover { background-image: url("01.jpg"); }
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can try to help you and not just the job for you.

Comment: you can use css animation, combine with class manipulation with jquery. Edit: if it is only on hover effects, you don't even need js. just pure css animation is good enough

Comment: `.jumbotron {
background-image: url("02.jpg");} .jumbotron:hover {background-image: url("01.jpg"); transition: 500ms; }`

Answer (score 2):

Using pure CSS you can use the `transition` property to animate it like below. This is probably not available in [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility) though.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("http://www.placecage.com/200/300");
  transition: 1000ms;
}

.jumbotron:hover {
  background-image: url("http://www.placecage.com/300/200");  
  transition: 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Life is an Art.</h1>
    <p style="font-size: 150%"><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas pulvinar nunc urna, non cursus enim ultricies in.</small></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a href="#">Learn More »</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Love the placeholder. gonna favorite that site. +1 very awesome

Comment: +1 for css solution!
i'd do transition:background 1000ms ease;

Comment: @Steve Well if you like that one, try these... http://www.nicenicejpg.com/ http://www.fillmurray.com/ http://placekitten.com/ http://baconmockup.com/

Comment: @Havihavi `ease` is the default transition anyway.

Comment: I dont know why but the transition isn't working..Its just simple hover. I am using Firefox 38.

Comment: @ShafiulAlam Does it work in the snippet above or just in your code?